# Passing down an ability in Pokémon Black 2

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

When I breed a female Gible (with sand veil as its ability) and a male Druddigon (with rough skin as its ability) will I be able to get a Gible with its hidden ability rough skin

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article about breeding](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-black-white-version-2/Breeding#Passing_Down_Abilities), the male's ability cannot be passed down by breeding. If the male *could* pass down abilities, it could lead to a monstrosity of different pokémon with unknown abilities.

The article also says that there is a 50/50 chance to get either ability if the pokémon has two possible abilities.  If the female has a rare ability from Pokémon Dream World, there is an 80% chance the ability will be passed down.

Comment: The important part is the last one, about Dream World abilities (they're also called Hidden Abilities). Only the female can pass these down in Gen 5.